# Rails running validations on custom model manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have custom model. It is working without database and includes some mixins from active record:

```
class Node
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :title, :content

  validates_presence_of :title, :content

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    # we want to run validations here
  end
end
```

Through googling got that it is possible to use `@object.validate`, but it complains about not having such method.

Help, please.

Comment: The `valid?` method should be available... is it possible to use that instead?

Comment: Somehow it is not working. Non-present fields are still being saved.

Comment: that sounds like another problem .. if you run `@object = Node.new` then `@object.valid?` in a rails console, does it give you an error?

Comment: Ok. I found my error. It was due to some before_filter in controller. Nevermind. @MateniaRossides ```valid?``` should be posted as answer. It is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct, `.validate` seems to be undefined.

`@object.valid?` should do the job for what you want.

Keep in mind, this returns a boolean value which you can use to control conditional behaviour based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to double re-check what is happening when I using ```valid?```.